# what is this "cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 2000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, algolia

I am getting this error most of white inserting data in database. This error start appearing after I use algolia search in my project. I don't know if it is because of algolia or anything else.

I tried to find algolia errors but didn't find any.

I want to know why this error is appearing and how i can solve it.

Comment: I think this is a network issue in your end, maybe the code tries to download Algolia response and is unable to resolve the DNS or something

Comment: is there any way to avoid it? i mean like exception so it doesn't effect other operations

Comment: Edit the question and post your how you're using Laravel Scout, the search function specifically